# dynamic data in pie high chart jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

i am using high chart to draw pie chart as flow

this is how i give static data this itemdata  should be loaded with array dynamically 
**Static intialization**

```
var itemdata = [
                      ['aloogobi', 42.0],
                      ['pannermakhani', 26.8],
                      {
                          name: 'Cholle',
                          y: 14.8,
                          sliced: true,
                          selected: true
                      },
                      ['mattuerpaneer', 6.5],
                      ['Jaipuri', 8.2],
                      ['Kolapuri', 0.7]
                  ];
```

an i am giving dynamic as follow

```
 for(var i=0;i<categoryGroup.length;i++){
     var temp=[categoryGroup[i][1],7.5];
     itemdata=itemdata+[temp]+',';
}
```

here categoryGroup is array that i want to fill in chart ,and after this foor loop i m using this in pie chart as follow but it show me last value with show single letter of last value in chart as below

[image]

Comment: didnot understand exactly what you are trying to do,but instead of itemdata=itemdata+[temp]+','; try itemdata.push(temp);

Comment: only in item data i want to load array as my value asvar itemdata = [
                      ['aloogobi', 42.0],
as var itemdata = [
                      [array[i]0], [array[i][1]],];                                                                                                                                     and use it in pie chart but it is not displaying chart properly as shown in image

Comment: can you tell what is in categoryGroup, the structure and sample data and also how are instializing itemdata

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle code?

Answer (score 0):

use `itemdata.push(temp);` instead of `itemdata=itemdata+[temp]+',';`